# Transpose of a matrix showing same results as original

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to transpose the matrix but getting the same matrix, this seems to be happening everytime and what is more confusing is that the element of list are swapped but not on this instance.

What is problematic is that I see no change in the end result as the swapping was made for nXn times in the loop.

```
inp = int(input())
mat = []
for i in range(inp):
    submat = list(map(int,input().split(',')))
    mat.append(submat)

print(mat)   
for i in range(len(mat)):
    for j in range(len(mat[0])):
        mat[i][j],mat[j][i] = mat[j][i],mat[i][j]
        
print(mat)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop in upper triangular matrix only ie from `0,1...len(mat)` row wise and `row+1, row+2, row+3..len(mat[0])` column wise

```
# your code goes here
inp = int(input())
mat = []
for i in range(inp):
    submat = list(map(int,input().split(',')))
    mat.append(submat)

print(mat)   
for i in range(len(mat)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(mat[0])):
        mat[i][j],mat[j][i] = mat[j][i],mat[i][j]
```

Comment: Very clear explanations.  Upvote it.  It's helpful for the OP to run the code in this great platform - https://pythontutor.com/

Comment: @DanielHao cool platform, helpful for people to visualize their code

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you are swapping every i, j twice (i, j and later j, i).